# Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm fit my MultinomialNB model with K-fold split.

I've tried to balance data with SMOTE (imblearn.over_sampling, lib)

```py
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(
                    fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
            ])

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold.split(train_data):

    train_sequencies = train_data.iloc[train_indices]['NAME']
    label_train = train_data.iloc[train_indices][['SEARCH','OPTIONS_VOLUME', 'OPTIONS_QUANTITY', 'OPTIONS_PORTION', 
                                                      'OPTIONS_WEIGHT', 'OPTIONS_SIZE', 'OPTIONS_CONCENTRATION', 
                                                      'OPTIONS_CONTENT', 'OPTIONS_MANUFACTURER']]

    test_sequencies = train_data.iloc[test_indices]['NAME']
    label_test = train_data.iloc[test_indices][['SEARCH','OPTIONS_VOLUME', 'OPTIONS_QUANTITY', 'OPTIONS_PORTION',
                                                'OPTIONS_WEIGHT', 'OPTIONS_SIZE', 'OPTIONS_CONCENTRATION', 
                                                'OPTIONS_CONTENT', 'OPTIONS_MANUFACTURER']]


    NB_pipeline.fit(train_sequencies, label_train)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_sequencies)

    confusion += confusion_matrics(test_sequencies, label_test)
    score = f1_score(test_sequencies, label_test)

    score.append(score)
```

I expect cross-validation of multi-label classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html) consists in fitting one classifier per class not per target.

Since [MultinomialNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) doesn't support Multioutput target data, you can fit one [MultinomialNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) per target by using [MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html). This is a simple strategy for extending classifiers that do not natively support multi-target classification.

```
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(MultinomialNB( fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),])
```

If you want to fit one classifier per class (the class is fitted against all the other classes.) and per target:

```
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB( fit_prior=True, class_prior=None)))),])
```